# Unable to build mule community from git repo

Tags: mule

I am trying to build the community mule from git repo. https://github.com/mulesoft/mule
I am using maven 3.8.1 and openjdk 11 on macos with m1 chip.
I use this command `mvn -DskipTests install` to build the project.

Here is the error

```
incompatible types: java.util.Map<org.mule.maven.pom.parser.api.model.ArtifactCoordinates,org.mule.maven.pom.parser.api.model.AdditionalPluginDependencies> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,org.mule.maven.pom.parser.api.model.AdditionalPluginDependencies>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build everything May 18 2023 on my Intel MacBook pro. Forget trying to build it all at once. There are issues in the order and dependencies that need to be fixed. Do `/modules/service` first. And then no `clean` but next run `mvn install -DskipTests` at just `/modules`. Then do `/core`. Basically when you get an error attribute it to poor Maven structure and testing.

Write back if this doesn't work. I've run Mule EE in Kubernetes before and I'm trying to do the same using CE because I can still develop a prototype but not need a license.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I git pulled again today, and try to build in that order. still failed. Just failed at different place, this time failing at "HTTP Service Definition" (sigh...)